# How can I substitute IDs in a string with corresponding values from a table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got 2 tables in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database - Rules and Items

A Rules record has Id and Expression, eg:

```
  1, "(1 AND 2)"
```

An Items record has Id and Name, eg:

```
  1, "Foo" 
  2, "Bar"
```

Is there a way to select all the rule expressions and substitute the items ids with their names in a single query?

```
SELECT Magic(Expression) FROM Rules WHERE Id = 1
```

will give me `"(Foo AND Bar)"`

I'm thinking of doing a .net console app, so I can leverage Regex, but if there's a way to do it in SQL, which isn't too messy, I'd rather go that route.

Comment: You could try using CLR function with regex

Comment: Is there a way of doing this with this simple example? Sure. Is there a way of doing it with every conceivable variation of expression? Not reliably. You will need a way of differentiating constant values from replacements. E.g. what about `(1 And 2) Or (3 > 5)`. Is that later expression `Element 3 > Element 5` or the boolean expression `[Element 3] > 5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a thing called a CLR Stored Procedure.
[MSDN CLR Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx)

So you could use regex from .net. It's not fast though. You could do a simple rule like that with string functions in sql, but more complex ones would cause you serious pain. Think I'd be tempted to do it outside of sql myself, if there's a lot of it.

Comment: Indeed, I think I will do it outside of sql. This is a once-off on a relatively small data set, so performance isn't a concern. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your Items table should really have a Foriegn Key to the Rules table then it would be a simple matter of joining the 2 tables.  However if an Item can be referenced from more than 1 rule they you'd need a XRef table that would allow you to have a many to many reference.  Using a CLR to perform a REGEX expression is going to seriously slow down your Select statement.  I would take a closer look at restructuring the tables to support what your application needs.

Comment: I agree in principle, but we initially tried storing complex logical expression in a normalised, relational way and it proved to be very unpleasant to maintain and work with, compared to "just" generating, parsing and processing a string.I knew about CLR but if I have to write .net code, I think I'll do it entirely in c#. Thank you for your help.